# Should I use Firebase Job Dispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I have an android app that gets FCM Data messages (contains Image URL).
When Data Message is received in `onMessageReceived()` I create a `FirebaseJobDispatcher` and a Job, then schedule the Job for downloading and saving image in local storage `dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob)`.

The download and save image Job extends `JobService`. When a Job is started I create a Thread to in which I download and save the Image, then I send a `BroadcastReceiver` to the Activity so that it displays the new image from Local Storage in ImageView using Picasso (code below):

```
private String imageName = "image.jpg";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update local storage content with new Image!");
        Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                // Delegating work to a new Thread since it can be long task (downloading Image and storing it to local file system)
                Thread storeImageThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + imageName);

                        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), imageName);
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                            ostream.flush();
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }finally {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.SendBroadcast");
                            //intent.putExtra("imageURL", remoteMessage.getData().get("image"));
                            intent.setAction("com.example.SendBroadcast");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                          //  sendBroadcast(intent);
                            sendOrderedBroadcast(intent,null);
                            //Tell the framework that the job has completed and does not need to be reschedule
                            jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
                        }
                    }
                });
                storeImageThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(jobParameters.getExtras().getString("image"))
                .into(target);


        return true;
    }
```

I am facing some problems with this architecture;
- The Job Service starts many times very late although I use **`setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))`**. So should I use a Firebase Job Dispatcher with Job Service for downloading and saving image in local storage? Is there any other alternative?

- Is there more performance and efficient way to update the activity after finishing download and saving image?
- I think Picasso uses separate Thread to download Image, so is my Thread use here correct?
- Many times I am getting ARN dialog and app crashes. So is there a more performance architecture proposal for my purpose?

Thanks in advance for any help from experts

Comment: Is there any support from experts?

Answer (score 0):

> So should I use a Firebase Job Dispatcher with Job Service for
>   downloading and saving image in local storage?

Because your application is running state when `onMessageReceived` is executed for FCM message. no need to use Firebase Job Dispatcher

> Is there any other alternative?

Yes, use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) for downloading image if app is not visible to user. save image in cache or sdcard and show it when app opened by user.

> The Job Service starts many times very late although I 
>    use setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))

WorkManager providing options for checking task is finished or not before starting same task again.

**OR**

If app is already running then use normal service like `IntentService` or `Service`.

Comment: Thanks. I googled WorkManager, it seems that it uses JobScheduler service to schedule jobs else FirebaseJobDispatcher if JobScheduler is not supported. Is there a big defference by using WorkManager? Is it riggered immediately when Message received? Is it possible to use Background Threads instead? `onMessageReceived()` Picasso starts a Thread for downloading Image from a URL and `onBitmapLoaded()` I start a new Thread for saving the downloaded Image on file system. So when to stop the Thread? how to know Activity status (on or off) before sending Broadcast?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Can i have your email